# Input value doesn't refresh correclty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a shopping basket which has a Refresh button:

[image]

when I change the quantity, the price field should be refreshed:

There is the button, and there is the quantity input field:

```
 @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr class="bg-danger btnDelete" data-id="1">
                        <td>@item.Name</td>
                        <td>@item.SupplierNo</td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control quantity" id="quantity" value="1" name="quantity" min="1" max="100" type="number" style="width:100px;" required>
                        </td>
                        <td style="color:red">@item.Price</td>
                        <td class="actions" data-th="">
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="test(this)" id="refreshBasket" data-id=@item.ID><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deleteFromBasket(this)" id="deleteFromBasket" data-id=@item.ID><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
```

This is the javascript function:

```
 <script>
function test(obj) {
    var $button = $(obj);
    var testId = $button.data("id"); //reading the data-id of clicked button
    var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
    var UrlSettings = {
        url: '@Url.Action("RefreshBasket", "Purchase")'
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: UrlSettings.url,
        data: { 'id': testId, 'quantity': quantity },
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
          location.reload();
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        }
    });

}
```

This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult RefreshBasket(int id, string quantity)
    {
        List<Product> cart = (List<Product>)Session["ShoppingCart"];
        Product product = productRepository.GetProductByID(id);
        if (cart == null)
        {
            return new JsonResult() { Data = new { Status = "ERROR" } };
        }

        List<ProductCategoriesVM> cartList = ConvertShoppingCartListToProductCategories(cart);

        if (product != null)
        {
            ProductCategoriesVM item = cartList.Where(p => p.ID == product.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            double parsedValue;
            double.TryParse(item.Price, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"), out parsedValue);

            double result = parsedValue * int.Parse(quantity);
            item.Price = result.ToString("0.00");

            var itemFromSession = cart.Where(p => p.Id == item.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            itemFromSession.AtpPrice = item.Price;
        }

        return View("PurchaseProduct", cartList);
    }
```

The problem is that sometimes the quantity value remains 1, although I change it in the shopping list, sometimes the quantity value remains the last changed value. sometimes it behaves correctly. I don't know what I do wrong? As you see I try to get the value like this: var quantity = $('#quantity').val(); There is another approach to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your quantity value is always from same input. Remember id should be unique for each element on page so change your jQuery code with this and remove id of input as well or make it diffrent:

```
function test(obj) {
var $button = $(obj);
var testId = $button.data("id"); //reading the data-id of clicked button
var quantity = $button.parents('tr').find('.quantity').val();
//or var quantity = $button.closest('tr').find('.quantity').val();
var UrlSettings = {
    url: '@Url.Action("RefreshBasket", "Purchase")'
}

$.ajax({
    url: UrlSettings.url,
    data: { 'id': testId, 'quantity': quantity },
    type: "post",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
      location.reload();
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I 'm getting the error: obj.parents is not a function,  if I use obj.closest('tr').find('.quantity').val(); I get the same error: obj.closest is not a function. Do you have any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: @Orsi sorry please replace obj with $button